# What array function be a more efficient choice for this mapping object and array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm formatting data for a D3 tree visualization, my children are both arrays and objects with more children objects. I need them to be in a children array for the tree to work. It's working now, but it feels like it's not a very efficient way to achieve this.

I have both angular and D3 methods available. I wrote this lengthy function in vanilla JS.

The data logged to the console is in the correct format. The unformatted data is the initial object.

Thanks for looking

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>


</style>

<body>

<div id=tree></div>
<script>
var unformattedData = {
  "city": "All Cities",
  "children": {
    "group_a": {
      "wins": "20"
    },
    "group_b": {
      "wins": "15"
    },
    "group_c": [{
      "city": "NYC",
      "wins": "25",
      "losses": "2",
      "children": {
        "group_a": {
          "wins": "5"
        },
        "group_b": {
          "wins": "3"
        },
        "group_c": [{
          "city": "SFO",
          "wins": "3",
          "losses": "1",
          "children": {
            "group_a": {
              "wins": "0"
            },
            "group_b": {
              "wins": "0"
            },
            "group_c": [{
              "city": "LON",
              "wins": "2",
              "losses": "0"
            }],
            "group_d": [{
              "city": "LAX",
              "wins": "2",
              "losses": "0"
            }]
          }
        }, {
          "city": "SFO",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "1",
          "children": {
            "group_a": {
              "wins": "0"
            },
            "group_b": {
              "wins": "0"
            },
            "group_c": [{
              "city": "LON",
              "wins": "2",
              "losses": "0"
            }],
            "group_d": [{
              "city": "LAX",
              "wins": "2",
              "losses": "0"
            }]
          }
        }, {
          "city": "NYC",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {
            "group_a": {
              "wins": "0"
            },
            "group_b": {
              "wins": "0"
            },
            "group_c": [{
              "city": "LON",
              "wins": "2",
              "losses": "0"
            }],
            "group_d": [{
              "city": "LAX",
              "wins": "2",
              "losses": "0"
            }]
          }
        }],
        "group_d": [{
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "1",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "city": "SFO",
      "wins": "1",
      "losses": "1",
      "children": {
        "group_a": {
          "wins": "1"
        },
        "group_b": {
          "wins": "1"
        },
        "group_c": [{
          "city": "PDX",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "PHX",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "JFK",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "1",
          "children": {}
        }],
        "group_d": [{
          "city": "LGB",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "SEA",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "JFK",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "city": "NYC",
      "wins": "1",
      "losses": "0",
      "children": {
        "group_a": {
          "wins": "1"
        },
        "group_b": {
          "wins": "1"
        },
        "group_c": [{
          "city": "LON",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "LON",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "LON",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "1",
          "children": {}
        }],
        "group_d": [{
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "LGB",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }, {
          "city": "PHX",
          "wins": "1",
          "losses": "0",
          "children": {}
        }]
      }
    }],
    "group_d": [{
      "city": "CLT",
      "wins": "6",
      "losses": "0",
      "children": {
        "group_a": {
          "wins": "0"
        },
        "group_b": {
          "wins": "0"
        },
        "group_c": [{
          "city": "LON",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0"
        }],
        "group_d": [{
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0"
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "city": "DAL",
      "wins": "5",
      "losses": "0",
      "children": {
        "group_a": {
          "wins": "0"
        },
        "group_b": {
          "wins": "0"
        },
        "group_c": [{
          "city": "LON",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0"
        }],
        "group_d": [{
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0"
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "city": "BUR",
      "wins": "4",
      "losses": "0",
      "children": {
        "group_a": {
          "wins": "0"
        },
        "group_b": {
          "wins": "0"
        },
        "group_c": [{
          "city": "LON",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0"
        }],
        "group_d": [{
          "city": "LAX",
          "wins": "2",
          "losses": "0"
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
};

var formattedData = {};

function createTree(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      if (d.children.typeof = 'Obj') {
        var childrenArray = [];

        if (d.children.group_b) {
          d.children.group_b.content = 'hello';
          d.children.group_b.message_group = 'group b';
          childrenArray.push(d.children.group_b);
        }

        if (d.children.group_a) {
          d.children.group_a.content = 'goodbye';
          d.children.group_a.message_group = 'group a';
          childrenArray.push(d.children.group_a);
        }

        if (d.children.group_c) {
          d.children.group_c.forEach(function(child, index) {
            child.message_group = 'group c';
            childrenArray.push(child);
          });
        }

        if (d.children.group_d) {
          d.children.group_d.forEach(function(child, index) {
            child.message_group = 'group d';
            childrenArray.push(child);
          });
        }

        d.children = childrenArray.reverse();
        d.children.forEach(createTree);
      }
    }
    formattedData = d;
    console.log(formattedData);
}

createTree(unformattedData)

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why would it be not efficient? Seems you are only traversing every element only once

Comment: Theres no more efficient way, may theres a bit shorter way...

Comment: since this question appears to be about **working** code, it would be a better fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function createTree(d) {
if (d.children && d.children.typeof = 'Obj') {
    var childrenArray = [];
    //may a bit shorter way of assigning the props
    for(k in d.children){
    childrenArray.push(Object.assign(d.children[k],
   {
   group_b:{
      content:'hello',
      message_group:'group b',
   }
   group_a:{
       content:'goodbye',
      message_group:'group a'
   }
   }[k]||{});
   }
      //shorter way of if
      (d.children.group_c||[]).forEach(function(child, index) {
        child.message_group = 'group c';
        childrenArray.push(child);
      });

      (d.children.group_d||[]).forEach(function(child, index) {
        child.message_group = 'group d';
        childrenArray.push(child);
      });
    }
    //i think theres no need for this lines

    d.children = childrenArray.reverse();
    setTimeout(function(){d.children.forEach(createTree)});//=> recursion to walking,better performance
    }
}
```